# http.get with urls with spaces

Tags: node.js

playing around with node js and an image downloader. I stumbled on a problem with urls and `http.get`, which failed for me if the url contained spaces in the query. I managed to get around the problem by escaping just the url path myself. if I use `url.parse()` the path variable will be cut off at the first space. My solution works but I wondered if there is a better solution.

```
function downloadFileFromURL( file_url, callback ) 
{
    //-------------
    // really complicated way to get a http.get save path
    var protocol = url.parse( file_url).protocol;
    var host = url.parse( file_url ).host;
    var full_domain =  protocol + '//' + host;
    var escaped_path =  escape(file_url.substring( full_domain.length ));

    var options = {
        host: host
      , port: 80
      , path: escaped_path
    }

    var file_url_info = url.parse( file_url );
    var file_path = path.join( __dirname, 'images', path.basename(file_url) );

    var request = http.get( options , function(res){

        var imagedata = ''
        res.setEncoding('binary')

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            imagedata += chunk;
        })

        res.on('end', function(){

            fs.writeFile( file_path, imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
                if (err) callback( err );
                else {
                    callback( null, file_path );
                }
            })
        })

    })
}
```

Comment: Where are the spaces coming from in the first place?

Comment: Valid URLs aren't allowed to contain unescaped spaces. Where does the argument to `downloadFileFromURL` come from?

Comment: its a path to an image like this for example, parsed out of an rss feed: 'http://payload71.cargocollective.com/1/0/31246/3728074/13-Screen Shot 2012-07-05 at 12.28.08 PM.png'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try running it through [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

```
var encoded_url = encodeURI(file_url);
```

Comment: this makes out of `http://payload74.cargocollective.com/1/0/31246/3793794/NIKE- Inc. - Nike and Tom Sachs present Tom Sachs- NIKECraft.png`

the following: 


`%2F1%2F0%2F31246%2F3793794%2FNIKE-%20Inc.%20-%20Nike%20and%20Tom%20Sachs%20present%20Tom%20Sachs-%20NIKECraft.png`

Comment: actually just noticed in your link: `string.replace(searchvalue,newvalue)` would be the way to go, just replacing spaces only and leave the rest

Comment: @ThomasTraum you're right. I think you want encodeURI instead of encodeURIComponent